# Should implementations of Runnable allow for concurrent calls to run() on the same instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, software-design, runnable

If I have a class that implements `java.lang.Runnable`, there is technically nothing stopping multiple threads from calling `run` concurrently on the *same* instance of the `Runnable`. Example:

```
Runnable r = new MyRunnable();

//start thread 1
new Thread(r).start();

//start thread 2
new Thread(r).start();
```

This is not really a problem if the `run` method is entirely "self-contained" (i.e. doesn't rely on any private instance members), because there are no variables shared between threads, so your `Runnable` can never get a "corrupted" internal state. But I think in most cases, your `Runnable` *will* have some private instance members that it manipulates in `run`, so what to do?

To use an example, my `MyRunnable` class has a private `mode` field. The primary purpose is to cleanly stop the `run` method (by setting `mode` to `STOPPED`), but it has other uses as well.

```
public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    enum Mode { RUNNING, PAUSED, STOPPED, FASTFORWARDING, REWINDING; }

    private volatile Mode mode;

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        mode = Mode.RUNNING;
        while (mode != Mode.STOPPED)
        {
            //do stuff. possibly other changes to the mode.
        }
    }

    public void setMode(Mode mode)
    {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public Mode getMode()
    {
        return mode;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if I execute multiple threads concurrently for the *same* instance of`MyRunnable` (like shown earlier), any change to the `mode` could affect concurrently running threads in different ways. For example, if a thread sets the `mode` to `STOPPED`, another thread might change the `mode` to something else before every other thread even gets to see that it was set to `STOPPED`. This could easily prevent threads from exiting the while loop.

**So how do I design a `Runnable` to be "concurrently usable"?** Is it even possible? Is it not worth it? Is there something like C#'s [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) attribute I can use (which I think would be perfect in this context)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is much more common to construct multiple instances of your `MyRunnable` in this scenario as opposed to protecting them against multiple use:

```
//start thread 1
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
//start thread 2
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
```

The whole purpose of having multiple threads working is to achieve good parallel computing.  If the threads need to lock common resources (like work queues, etc.) then fine but writing your `Runnable`s to make them "concurrently usable" should not be done as a matter of course -- there should be good reasons to do so.

> Is it even possible?

Certainly it is possible.  Threads share resources all of the time between them.  However in your case with the `Mode mode` variable, this should be done with multiple instances of your `Runnable` class.

If multiple threads are calling common code, one pattern you might consider is using `ThreadLocal` to store per-thread information.  But storing fields inside of multiple instances of your `MyRunnable` will be more efficient than having one `MyRunnable` instance with the `mode` stored in a `ThreadLocal`.

> Is it not worth it?

It is certainly *not* worth it if this is done on principle.  Again, the whole point of forking the threads is to have them be as separate as possible from other threads to utilize multiple processores.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you design any other method or class to be threadsafe.  There is nothing inherently different with a Runnable.

The C# ThreadStatic is the equivalent of a [ThreadLocalVariable](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-thread-local-%E2%80%93-how-use), but whether that is the appropriate solution here is anyones guess since there is no way for us to know what behaviour you want you class to follow.

If you want to effectively have each thread run have an independent execution of your Runnable (with regards to state) it would make more sense (and be much simpler) to have different instances.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it isn't worth it.

The cost of creating a new instance of your `Runnable` can't be too high anyway. If it is, you have to look at how to factor out the parts that are expensive to initialise and make sure they are thread-safe.

You can of course also use [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variables, which on the whole are incredibly useful but probably not in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't say I have a lot of experience with MP in Java so I won't try to speak to common usage, but after reading the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) docs, it sounds like Runnable is intended to be exactly what the name implies: a runnable object. Specifically, the docs mention using Runnable in cases where you do not wish to implement Thread, but desire a similar concept. I actually think that makes Runnable ideal for classes which encapsulate parallel or concurrent algorithms. Certainly, there is nothing to imply that you should not or can not specifically design Runnable for concurrency. Of course, that in itself (depending on the task) is much more than a single SO question could address.

Edit: I should clarify, I mentioned encapsulating parallel or concurrent algorithms within a Runnable, but I meant to convey that it might also make sense to encapsulate a task within the Runnable, and then let the caller determine whether to allocate parallel resources to that task by invoking it in concurrent threads, for instance. My point is just that, as the docs imply, if you can imagine an object being run (in any context) then Runnable may be a good bet!

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP's question is in certain scenarios when the Runnable is resource heavy, is there a way to avoid recreating these Runnables?

My experience is that you could always create lightweight Runnables to refer to heavy weight resources (such as huge arrays, etc.). Avoid calling the same Runnables on multiple threads, but create a different Runnable for each Thread is a better practice in my opinion.